# select option in html select using keys javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqtransform

I have used `jqtransform` to change the default look of form select. Now i couldn't select an option using arrow keys. I need to `select options` using `keys`. How to do that?

Here is my html

```
<form>
<select name="test">
<option value="" selected="selected">option 1</option>
<option value="01">option 2</option>
<option value="02">option 3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Here is my internal script

```
$(function(){
    $('form').jqTransform({imgPath:'images/'});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I think that Plugins disables keyboard navigation. you can confirm here:
http://j.mp/VlZNSd
in the left side bar you can try it yourself. It does not work. If your interest is to keep that design change plugin to a better one like: http://j.mp/VySpJ2 you will keep the design and it will work with keyboard. I don't have the solution to your problem this is a work around.